# VMware host-only networking Internet access

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vmware

I am running a Ubuntu Linux VM using VMware Player on a Windows 7 host.

I don't want to connect directly to the network or use NAT; I need host-only networking but also need Internet access. How can I do this?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, because I think you are approaching it the wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the day you will have to either use some form of NAT or Bridge. If you can't/don't want to let VMWare do it for you, you can have windows do it by enabling Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on the host's connection.

```
1. Go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet ->Network and Sharing Center
2. Click on 'Change adapter settings'
3. Right click the connection you wish to share (the one which does have access to the net)
4. Click properties
5. Go to the sharing tab at the top of the window
6. Check the first checkbox
7.(optional) select the VMWare adapter responsible for the host only connection with the guest from the drop down box.
```

Comment: All ICS really does is... NAT. just in a different place.

Comment: You're right, edited answer to reflect that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Host-only networking provides a network connection between the virtual machine and the host computer, using a virtual Ethernet adapter that is visible to the host operating system. This approach can be useful if you need to set up **an isolated virtual network**." - [Host-only networking](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html)

Answer (score 1):

if your host is a linux box you can set up your own NAT for the host-only vmware

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.60.150 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

where **172.16.60.150** is the IP of your vmware image 
and **eth0** is the interface with access to Internet